# @DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum not work

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

When I use `@DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum` I receive this error:

> Cannot marshall type class com.lib.dao.enums.main.ROLE without a custom marshaler or @DynamoDBDocument annotation.

Here is my code:

```
public enum ROLE {
    ADMIN,USER
}

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "user")
public class UserEntity extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
...
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "role_name")
    @DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum
    private ROLE roleName;

    public ROLE getRoleName() {
        return roleName;

    }

    public void setRoleName(ROLE roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: This happens when i want save new entity into database

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather old, and since then, the DynamoDB API has evolved. You did not specify which version you use, so I assume 1.0.x.

`@DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum` works for me when used on the enum:

```
@DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum
public enum ROLE {
    ADMIN,USER
}
```

---

I have another issue, which is, the implementation uses setters, and if the class is immutable, the mapper is not able to unmap this field (the setter is not found). But that's different topic.